# my laptop overall performance is slower than windows

Tags: drivers, performance, amd-graphics, intel-cpu

hi all is my amd driver really working ? cause my laptop is really slow ! i don't know the exact reason for the slowness i thought it maybe the gpu driver but i've checked and found this . so if it's functional what is the cause of this slowness !

```
*-display
   description: Display controller
   product: Venus XTX [Radeon HD 8890M / R9 M275X/M375X]
   vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
   version: 81
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
   resources: irq:50 memory:b0000000-bfffffff memory:d1000000-d103ffff ioport:3000(size=256) memory:d1040000-d105ffff
```

i've doubled check all other threads about the slowness nothing really helped me

i have core i5-5200U 2.2ghz
and 8 gb of ram

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of terminal output. Instead please [edit] your question and include the terminal output you wish to show, directly in your question. Also, your question is extremely vague. What exactly is slow? You're going to have to be more specific about what is slow exactly, for anyone to help you.

Comment: sorry for that mistake , i'm kinda sad because all of my threads "questions" need to be modified makes me feel so ignorant and angry from myself